# Error when drawing line in Graphics.DrawLine C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, graphics

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics l = e.Graphics;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        float angle = 0;
        float len = 100;
        PointF ori = new PointF(Width/2, 0);    
        PointF bob = new PointF(Width/2, len);
        while(true)
        {

            bob.X = ori.X + len * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
            bob.Y = ori.Y + len * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
            angle += 0.001F;
            l.DrawLine(p, ori.X, ori.Y, bob.X, bob.Y);
            l.DrawEllipse(p, bob.X - 15, bob.Y, 30, 30);
            if(angle == 360)
            {
                break;
            }
            l.Dispose();
        } 
    }
```

The error line is l.DrawLine(p, ori.X, ori.Y, bob.X, bob.Y).
Error type: System.ArgumentException. Error Message: Parameter is not valid.

At first I thought the issue was with the floats but the DrawLine allows for such datatypes. It loops through once the error seems to occur when angle>0. Its magnitude doesn't seem to be the issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. [UPDATE] Error seems to be with the l.Dispose

Comment: `l.Dispose();` makes the `Graphics` object invalid.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp you might want to add that as an answer

Comment: Do not `Dispose` -  `l.Dispose();` - the instance you *don't create*

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out. But now the previous graphic doesn't get removed. Any Ideas?

Comment: Call `Clear` on the `Graphics` instance.

Comment: You should also *strongly* consider changing that `while` loop in to a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the wrong `Dispose` call:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics l = e.Graphics;

    // Pen is IDisposable, that's why why wrap it into "using": it's you who created it 
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1)) {
      float angle = 0;
      float len = 100;
      PointF ori = new PointF(Width/2, 0);    
      PointF bob = new PointF(Width/2, len);

      while(true)
      {
        bob.X = ori.X + len * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
        bob.Y = ori.Y + len * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
        angle += 0.001F;

        l.DrawLine(p, ori.X, ori.Y, bob.X, bob.Y);
        l.DrawEllipse(p, bob.X - 15, bob.Y, 30, 30);

        // angle is float, that's why == is not recommended:
        // (you can well have 359.99999999999999) and thus == will never be true
        if (angle >= 360) 
            break;

        // l.Dispose(); // <- Wrong: it's not you who've created it
                        // (let system Dispose it) 
      } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an enhancement to @Dmitry's answer, I can offer this advice:

As a general rule, you shouldn't call `Dispose` on an object that you do not control the lifetime of.  You are getting an existing `Graphics` instance from the `Paint` event.  The control that raised the `Paint` event is what created that `Graphics` object, so it is responsible for calling `Dispose` on it when it is done with it, not you.

When you call `Dispose` on an object that you don't control, you effectively "rip the rug out from under" that code. This is bad, because that code could be expecting the instance to still be alive so that it can perform other operations on it.  By disposing it, you don't give it that chance.

You are doing the correct thing with your `Pen` instance, `p`, though.  You create it during the `using` statement, so you are responsible for it.  The `Using` handles that by automatically calling `Dispose` when execution leave the block.

If you had created the Graphics`instance yourself, with something like`Graphics.FromImage`, *then* you would be responsible for cleaning it up.